# Unable to locate id python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, web-scraping

I am using selinium in python to type the username automatically to the webbrowser. But it shows that it can't locate the id. I tried bing website. It works great. But in here, it fails.
Here's the website link:
[Website](https://chat.smackcoders.com/login)

Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/paulsteven/selinium_geok_driver/geckodriver')
print("Firefox Browser Invoked")
#driver.get('https://www.bing.com/')
#inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("sb_form_q")
driver.get('https://chat.smackcoders.com/login')
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("loginId")
inputElement.send_keys('smackalpha')
driver.quit()
```

The error i got:
Firefox Browser Invoked

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sel_auto.py", line 8, in <module>
    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("loginId")
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="loginId"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a wait condition for element to be present

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://chat.smackcoders.com/login'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
inputElement = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "loginId")))
inputElement.send_keys('smackalpha')
```